# SQLite executemany error when using multiple variables

Tags: python, sqlite, execute, executemany

```
import sqlite3

# Get the file name from the user
file_name = input("Enter the file name: ")

# Open the file and read the data
with open(file_name, "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
# Process the data and create a list of tuples
data = []
x = 2
xref = 1
yref = 148
l = 6
year = 1991
values = range(12)
date = ""
value = 0
monthNum = 0
for line in lines[6:]:
    monthValue = []
    line.strip()
    year = 1990 + (l-5) % 11.
    for i in values:
        monthValue.append(line.split())
        #monthValue[i] = line.split()
        monthNum = i+1
        date = "1/" + str(monthNum) + "/" + str(year)
        value = monthValue[i]
        data.append((xref, yref, date, value))

# Create a connection to the database
conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
c = conn.cursor()

# Create the table if it doesn't already exist
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data
             (Xref REAL, Yref REAL, Date TEXT, Value REAL)''')

# Insert the data into the table
c.executemany('INSERT INTO data VALUES (:xref, :yref, :date, :value)', data)

# Commit the changes and close the connection
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The last line in the above code is flagging up an error "InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type." parameter 3 is the date string, which consists of multiple mini strings as shown in the top line. Am I doing this incorrectly? why is it flagging this up as an issue?

I have tried replacing the executemany parameters with '?' and '%s' and also tried changing the double quotes around the mini strings into single quotes such as '1/' instead of "1/" on the top line

EDIT: I have added a smaller version of the loop that i am using to demonstrate more accurately how my program works

EDIT 2: monthValue array stores a list of values read in from a line from a file separated by a space. the line in the file looks something like the below

100 250 400 300 100 230 300 405 300 530 510 350

and then each value is assigned to a month from the monthNum variable being i+1

EDIT 3: Just been informed that 'parameter 3' is referring to the 4th paramter as it starts from 0, so this is the value parameter. here is more info about the value parameter to clarify

`value` parameter is assigned to one of the numbers in the example line in edit 2. for month 1, `value` stores the first value of that line, for month 2 it stores the second value of that line etc. The associated date for each value is therefore different and each date and value pair are stored in data for the relevant field. Hope this helps

EDIT 4: The code isnt that long so I will just post the whole code to make it simpler. The file being read from has several lines of integer values separated by a space. each value is the data for a specific year and month. the 10 rows are for 10 different years and the 12 columns are for 12 different months. See below for an example

3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

Comment: When using named parameters such as `:xref`, I thought the `data` argument had to be a dictionary (or in the case of `executemany()`, a list of dictionaries), not a plain list of values...

Comment: @JohnGordon yeah it actually is, sorry i should have shown more of the code, but the second line of code, where the items are appended to data, is actually performed dozens of times. I have also tried using '?' and '%s' in place of the named parameters

Comment: _but the second line of code, where the items are appended to data, is actually performed dozens of times_ So make a smaller example program that has a lot less data, but still demonstrates the same error.

Comment: @JohnGordon ok will do

Comment: `data` is (apparently?) still a plain list of values, not a list of dicts...

Comment: Also, I believe "parameter 3" actually refers to `value`, not `date` (because python lists start at zero).  What is `value`? This code doesn't show that..

Comment: @JohnGordon idk what you mean by dictionaries, but data stores 12 instances of a set of 4 values. But either way, do you have any suggestions on how do modify the executemany method or any part of it that may help solve the problem? Thanks :)

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry, ill add that in

Comment: _and then each value is assigned to a month from the monthNum variable being i+1_ This doesn't help.  It's too vague.  I need to see **the actual value** of the `value` parameter.

Comment: @JohnGordon ```value``` parameter is assigned to a one of the numbers in the example line in edit 2. for month 1, ```value``` stores the first value of that line, for month 2 it stores the second value of that line etc. The associated date for each value is therefore different and each date and value pairs are stored in data for the relevant field. Hope this helps

Comment: Well, that's what you **think** the code is doing.  But since you're getting this error, I suspect the code has some mistake, and is actually doing something else you didn't expect.  If you don't show us the actual code, or the actual values being passed to the query, it's very hard for us to help.

Comment: It might be a lot easier to debug if you temporarily stop using `executemany()`, and instead have a loop that calls `execute()` once for each item in `data`.  That way you can print the specific values that cause the error.

Comment: @JohnGordon ok ill just post the whole code

Comment: You said you're also reading in data from a file, so you'll need to post that too.

Comment: @JohnGordon that should be everything added now, thank you for taking your time out for this, much appreciated. if you have any other suggestions about what the potential problems are, please feel free to let me know :)

Comment: Running this code with the sample file, I see that each row in `data` has a _list_ of number strings as the fourth item.  So that would appear to be the problem -- `value` is actually a list, which cannot be used as the expected `Real` datatype.

Comment: That is really interesting and helpful. value is meant to just me a single value. The code determining what value stores, is the following
 
```for i in values:
        monthValue.append(line.split()
        monthNum = i+1
        date = "1/" + str(monthNum) + "/" + str(year)
        value = monthValue[i]
        data.append((xref, yref, date, value))
```

do you know what is making value store a list?

Comment: `monthValue.append(line.split())` The split function returns a list.  So you're appending an entire list to `monthValue`, and therefore `monthValue` is a list-of-lists.  So when you assign `value = monthValue[i]`, `value` is one of those sub-lists.

Comment: Also, as a side comment, I hope this illustrates why _describing_ your code was not enough.  I had to see the _actual_ code to really know what it was doing.

Comment: @JohnGordon, no, it is meant to be a list of the values that are separated by spaces in the file. do you know how i can change it to that

Comment: @JohnGordon im guessing it would be monthValue[] = line.split() but that doesnt work

Comment: I'm not familiar with how you're using the data, so I don't know exactly how to fix it.  But a good start would be for you to add some `print()` statements so you can see exactly what is in `data.`  Add this line after the `for` loop is finished, but before the database connection: `for d in data: print(d)`

Comment: That will show you exactly what is in each row of `data`, and once you can see it, hopefully you will know how to fix it.

Comment: @JohnGordon with your help, I have fixed it, thanks so much. I had made it into 12 separate array values. I knew you were meant to do that but i just wanted a neater way of doing it i guess